# How to capture from webcam in Linux using Mono?

Tags: c#, .net, linux, mono, beagleboard

How can I capture a frame from a [video-4-linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video4Linux) device (e.g.: /dev/video0) using Mono and C#? OS is [Angstrom Linux](http://www.angstrom-distribution.org/) running on [BeagleBoard](http://beagleboard.org/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have done v4l2 capture using C.  This is probably the only language I would chose to do it in as well.  There are a lot of low level calls you need to make into the driver.  You need to map kernel memory into your app and copy buffers.  You also have to set a ton of configuration for the device.  If you need to I would consider writing a C library and using Platform Invoke.  Another alternative is to write two programs and send the data over to your C# app via some sort of IPC.

Comment: @Nate hi nate is there any possiblity to share your code. i amtrying to do sth similar

Comment: @FloodGravemind sorry it's been so long I no longer have access to that code.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Emgu CV for this, it specifically advertises that it can be compiled using Mono.

Main Site: http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page
Compiling in Mono:  http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Compiling_with_Monodevelop
Sample Code for Capturing Webcam Video: http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Camera_Capture_in_7_lines_of_code

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Mono or C# on linux, but you may have to write an interface module that exposes the diver API, or a reasonable abstraction.  I think you then might be able to import the module in the C# code.  It looks like Mono does support the DLLImport.

(http://www.mono-project.com/Interop_with_Native_Libraries)